# Eclipse with Webfaction and Django

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, webfaction

This is my first time purchasing a hosting and I opted for Webfaction.com to host my Django application. So far, i've been using Eclipse to write all my code and manage my Django application and I'm not ready to use VIM as a text editor yet. Now my question is, how can I use Eclipse to write my code and manage all my files while being connected to my webfaction account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do that. Your host is for hosting. Your personal machine is for developing.

Edit and run your code locally. When it's ready, upload it to Webfaction. Don't edit code on your server.